# Store java.util.List into GAE Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This is my idea of storing JSON and JSON-like documents "natively" into the GAE Datastore:

```
protected void createEntity(Key parent, Map obj){   
    try {
        Entity e = new Entity(
                parent == null ? createKey(_kind, (String) obj.get(OBJECT_ID)) : parent);  
        Iterator it = obj.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) it.next();
            if (obj.get(key) == null){
                e.setProperty(key, null);
            } else if (obj.get(key) instanceof String) {
                setProperty(e, key, obj.get(key));
            } else if(obj.get(key) instanceof Number) {
                setProperty(e, key, obj.get(key));
            } else if(obj.get(key) instanceof Boolean) {
                setProperty(e, key, obj.get(key));
            } else if(obj.get(key) instanceof List) {
                // Problem area, right way to store a list? 
                // List may contain JSONObject too!
            } else if(obj.get(key) instanceof Map){
                                    // Update: Ooops, this cause StackOverFlow error!
                                    Key pKey = createKey(e.getKey(), _kind, (String) obj.get(key)); 
                                    e.setProperty(key, pKey.toString()); // not sure?
                createEntity(pKey, obj);
            }
        }   
        _ds.put(e);
    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e){

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

The approach is recursive put, where GAE supported non-collection properties are stored directly into the Entity's property. Then for `Map`s a new entity is created with parent key having the current Entity key, and so forth.

The basis of the supported types of my JSON interface is this: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

The problem I have now is that I'm not sure how to deal with `java.util.List`, and how to store it maybe in a manner like the Map.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: so your question is about how to convert list to map?

Comment: Not really, just how to store a java.util.List to the Datastore, without serializing it

Comment: Did you give a look at Gson to do the job instead of JSON Simple?

Comment: Yes, I know Gson, I'm curious how can that help.